# How to reuse get_template_part() containing a simple loop to work with AJAX correctly?

Tags: ajax, get-template-part

I've got simple loop in `standard-loop.php` file (which, the file, is located in `inc/loop` folder):

```
if ( have_posts() ) :

    while ( have_posts() ) :

        the_post();
        the_content();

    endwhile;

endif;
```

Then in `index.php` I'm getting that file as a part of a template:

```
get_header();

get_template_part( 'inc/loop/standard', 'loop' );

get_footer();
```

Now I've got my wp_ajax function in `functions.php`:

```
function blank_frontend_ajax() {

    $url      = $_POST['postUrl'];
    $post_id  = url_to_postid( $url );
    $post_data = get_post( $post_id );

    get_template_part( 'inc/loop/standard', 'loop' );


    wp_die();

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_frontend_ajax', 'blank_frontend_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_frontend_ajax', 'blank_frontend_ajax' );
```

And finally my jQuery AJAX:

```
function desktopAjax() {

    jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'click', '.menu-item a', function( event ) {

        var postUrl = jQuery( this ).attr( 'href' );

        event.preventDefault();

        jQuery.ajax({

            url: blankAjax.ajaxUrl,
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action: 'frontend_ajax',
                postUrl: postUrl,
            },

            success: function( postObject ) {

                // jQuery( '#main' ).empty().append( postObject );

                console.log( postObject );

            }

        });

    });

}
```

Now, I'd like to use the same template part in index.php and my AJAX function. I know that I could pass query arguments (i.e. post ID) via `set_query_var()` into `get_template_part()` and retrieve it later on with `get_query_var()` but doing the same inside of index.php wouldn't be a bit of overkill (we have a post ID inside of index.php already hence no need to pass post ID into `get_template_part()`)? How could I rewrite whatever is inside of get_template_part() to work properly in case of loading in index.php and my AJAX fuction as well, and omit all unnecesary bits of code at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've used and seen, you don't put the whole loop into the Template Part, just the layout. The fact is you're always going to have a loop of some kind, the difference is the layout of the contents of that loop. You should break it out like this:

```
if( have_posts() ) {

    while( have_posts() ) {

        the_post();
        get_template_part( 'inc/loop/layout', 'simple' );

    }

}
```

Now if you *really* want to pull the exact same query in your AJAX call you could say:

```
rewind_posts();

ob_start();

// Same loop as above

$output = ob_get_clean();
```

The `rewind_posts()` will start the global post loop back at index 0 so you can run the loop over again. In reality, you're more likely to create a new WP_Query and loop though whatever those posts are ( offset? pagination? ) and run through the same loop method with the new WP_Query object but still using the same simple layout template part:

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

ob_start();

if( $query->have_posts() ) {

    while( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'inc/loop/layout', 'simple' );

    }

}

$output = ob_get_clean();
```

In the end we're just using output buffering to loop though any objects but the template part provides those objects with the same kind of layout.

Comment: So in general is it a bad practice to put the whole loop into `get_template_part()`? But what if loop differs significantly between different post types? Having above index.php I would need to write the whole loop again and again for different post types. When I put the whole loop in 'get_template_part()' it gives me cleaner code.

Comment: The idea is that you need a loop in each template file and usually they're not custom loops but the normal Loop. As suggested above it just allows you to use a layout easily for both a custom loop and normal WP loop without needing to build 2 template parts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77824/discussion-between-daniel-and-howdy-mcgee).